# Fundamental group of the complement of the closed disk in $\mathbb R^{3}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the fundamental group of the complement of the closed disk in $\mathbb R^{3}$ ?

i.e $X = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^{3} \ |  \ z=0, \ x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1\}$

what is $\pi_{1}(\mathbb R^{3}-X)$ ?

Comment: Your space can be contracted to $S^2$, so the fund. group is trivial.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking that way we can contract the closed disk to a point then our space has homotopy type of $R^{3}-{0}$. Then this means that the complement of the disk can be contracted to complement of the point, is that right ?

Comment: Yes, but that's also homotopy-equivalent to $S^2$.

Comment: okay, thanks for help, by the way this is NOT a homework question, I am gonna a take Top prelim, and it is past top prelim question

Comment: "Then this means that the complement of the disk can be contracted to complement of the point, is that right ?" $S^2$ is not contractible, but it is simply connected.

Comment: Think too about the fact that , unlike the case of $R^2$, a curve has enough space in $R^3-D$ to avoid the potential hole of D, and contract to a point.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in comments. The space is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$, so the fundamental group is trivial.